# Asp.net C# - checkbox control won't stay true after code-behind runs

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, code-behind, autopostback

Front HTML

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSend" runat="server" Text="Send?" />
```

The code that triggers the code behind

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
                runat="server" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Status" />
```

The code that runs in the code behind

```
protected void ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    this.chkSend.Checked = True;
}
```

When get back to the front end , the checkbox isn't checked. Any Ideas?

If it helps, this particular view is using Multi-views to which I'm new to.

Comment: Why not just set it to checked in the html **<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSend" runat="server" Text="Send?" checked/>**

Comment: Oh, because I'm running some Database validation on it > removed that bit for simplicity.

Comment: Are you using Ajax? Could you post code so that we can replicate the issue? Otherwise, we won't be able to tell what causes the issue.

Comment: Is there an UpdatePanel anywhere on your page? Do you have any other code that manipulates the `Checked` state?

Comment: @Win no ajax just a simple user control using "Autopostback=true" - A button if you must know.

Comment: @mason No sorry no update Panel.Just the autopostback routines that changes the value of chkSend to true

Comment: As others have stated you need to show specific code.  Once you take the time to actually look at the code you'll probably see your problem.  As you have posted it the code above will work.  Please try to frame your question  in the best detail possible to get the best answer possible.  You'll find that when you do that you can usually answer your own questions.

Comment: Is ViewState enabled?

Comment: @mason Yes I believe it is. Would that interfere?

Comment: No. But if it were disabled that might explain the behavior.

Comment: @AdamHeeg heres all the code that you need, nothing else runs. Unless theres something in the Mutliview i'm not familiar with but I'm stepping threw this and nothing else is running.

Comment: perhaps you're getting closer to answering your own question now.  Just for kicks I made a new web form with the exact code you have above and the check box works fine.  I've not used multi views, but that is one spot to look.  Until you actually show your code we can only guess.